# Sharing blogger post on Facebook not working properly anymore

Tags: facebook, image, blogger

I write a blog but now nothing about programming.

Until some time ago, whenever I shared a new post on FB it chooses the first image of the post and that was fine (although I'd prefer to control which one to share every time). And it also got the title of the post correctly.

Now it always chooses the header picture of the blog and inserts the blog's title and description instead. Also, if I try to share the blog itself it chooses not the header picture but some old one from one given post...

FB debugger gives me this:

"og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big enough. Please define a chosen image using the og:image meta tag, and use an image that's at least 200x200px and is accessible from Facebook. Image 'http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-vVHBaAssg-E/VdiSUEICydI/AAAAAAAAApw/Tsmhu4ZefTk/s1600/dpca%2Bblog%2Bcover%2Bv3.png' will be used instead. Consult (...) for more troubleshooting tips.
To find the object, these are the redirects we had to follow"

But the pictures in the post (or the blog's header) are in fact larger than 200x200.

I've added code as suggested in FB and bloggers tutorials but still no juice...

What's wrong?

I'm using AddThis as the sharing "platform".
Example post: http://doportocomamor.blogspot.pt/2016/02/brincar-com-o-fogo.html

thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Did you specify an image via the `og:image` metatag?

Comment: This is what the code looks like:
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mxqyjmtnedhkrlb/og%20code.png?dl=0)

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you post the code here instead of a screenshot? it doesn't help if is a screenshot, makes searching and reproducing problem harder. I couldnt find an og Image tag in that screenshot.